# I can't show the time in output.Even when i typed true (Y or y)

Tags: c, function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define timeteller(choose) (choose == 'Y' || choose == 'y') ? __TIME__ :"ok we dont show time now .."

int main (){
    int choose1;
    printf("do u want to learn time ?...\n");
    scanf(" %c",&choose1);

    if (timeteller(choose1) ){
        printf("%s",timeteller(choose1));
    }
    else {
        printf("%s",timeteller(choose1));
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the point of the `if`? It prints the same thing in both cases.

Comment: And `timeteller` always returns a true value, since all strings are truthy.

Comment: `choose1` needs to be `char`, not `int`.

Comment: When I fix that type error, the code compiles with no warnings and it prints the time.

Comment: That macro doesn't fill any other purpose but to confuse _you_, the programmer. It made the program far worse. Get rid of it. Writing function-like macros just for the heck of it is one of the worst things you can do in C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a version that works and is a bit cleaner:

- Macro name in full caps; common C code convention.
- Let macro only check the user input.
- Put macro parameter between `( )`: `(choose)`.  Not needed here but it's a common convention to [avoid issues with more complex expressions as argument](http://c-faq.com/cpp/safemacros.html).
- Nice code formatting.
- Printing newline to get nice program output.

BTW, it would probably have been better to use a function, instead of a macro.  But that's a whole other subject.

The reason why it didn't work with `int choose1;` is that after you define it, `choose1` contains 'random' bytes from the stack.  Then your `scanf()` writes only one of these bytes to the entered character value, but the remaining bytes still contain stack garbage.

Just add `printf("%d\n", choose1);` before and after your `scanf()` and you'll see.

Because of this, in official terms your program results in 'undefined behaviour'.  Your program could have worked if `choose1` coincidently got the value `0` from the stack or if your compiler/platform was friendly and initialized it to `0`.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    #define IS_Y(choose) ((choose) == 'Y' || (choose) == 'y')

    int main()
    {
        char choose;

        printf("do u want to learn time ?...\n");
        scanf(" %c", &choose);

        if (IS_Y(choose))
        {
            printf("%s", __TIME__);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Ok, we don't show time now ...");
        }

        printf("\n");
        
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You lost the space in `scanf(" %c", &choose)`.  Granted, in this context it doesn't matter much, but if there was prior input, it matters a lot.  See [`scanf()` leaves the newline in the input buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5240789/15168) for details.